OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallBack Not Available in .NET Android Maui
I am in the process of converting my Xamarin.Android app to .Net Android Maui due to the ended support for Xamarin. One of the functions involved in my app is overriding the hardware back button. In Xamarin.Android, I did this with no problem using OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallback & inheriting from OnBackPressedCallback. Inheriting from OnBackPressedCallback is no problem, but the AddCallback method seems to be missing from OnBackPressedDispatcher. What should I do to add my callback to the Activity? (NOTE: My app is Android only, so most of my code will be the same, I just need to replace the Xamarin-based code with the Maui-based equivalents). Any ideas? Thanks!

https://www.google.com/search?q=maui+onbackbuttonpressed+site:stackoverflow.com

Is that code for .NET Android MAUI, or just regular MAUI? I was pretty sure that I was supposed to be using things like OnBackPressedCallback & OnBackPressedDispatcher? In Microsoft's migration instructions, the only major changes were with Xamarin.Essentials, which is not related to this.

the point is that there are multiple existing questions about this topic

@Nathan Sokalsi,
I'm sorry, but I gave you the wrong project name. The project that has the OnBackPressedCallback is called NavigationGraph7Net7. But as I said earlier, I no longer use it because it is no longer necessary. You won't find it in NavigationGraph8Net8 or any later projects. Could you explain why you think you need it? What are you trying to do with it? Also, what version of Android are you targeting, and what version of .Net?
you also have PackageReferences using Xamarin, which is what we are supposed to be moving away from.
I have already explained the above on the MS forum, but for some reason, several of your questions and their answers have been deleted from there. The last time I saw them was Friday evening (25/10), my time (AU), but now they are gone.
You seem to be confused by the name Xamarin in the package names. They were never removed, and we aren't moving away from them with .Net. They are still just as pertinent as they ever were.
You also seem to be confused by the inclusion of MAUI. If you are writing an Android-only app, you should refer to it as .NET for Android. I'd suggest removing the maui tag in your questions, as it confuses those offering help.
It is only when you are doing cross-platform that MAUI comes into it. If you look on Discord/DotNetEvolution/#Android, you'll see a post 23/10/24 from jpobst, one of the MS Android team members, which should help clarify it for you.
Xamarin.Android -> .NET for Android
Xamarin.Forms -> MAUI
Xamarin was already confusing because to some people it meant Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS and to others, it meant Xamarin.Forms
unfortunately we cannot change the NuGet package names as they will break the whole ecosystem, so they still say Xamarin even though they are .NET for Android/MAUI packages.
Do you still need an answer regarding your now-deleted RecyclerView question?
To specifically answer your question about OnBackPressCallback. You would need the NuGet Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity, which you probably already have either directly or transitively.
Definition is:
AndroidX.Activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher OnBackPressedDispatcher
To use it, for instance, in a fragment
onBackPressedCallback = new NavFragmentOnBackPressedCallback(this, true);
RequireActivity().OnBackPressedDispatcher.AddCallback(ViewLifecycleOwner, onBackPressedCallback); 


Thank you for those clarifications, I think the fact that Xamarin is still in the package names is what was confusing me (I was removing all packages where I saw the name Xamarin, when those were exactly what I was supposed to be using). You are correct that I was a little confused by the MAUI name, so it is good to know that I now understand what is what. I think I will be able to figure out the rest of the RecyclerView, now that I am including the necessary packages. I haven't figured out the BackPressed stuff, is there a good tutorial or site for that? (I am targeting API 34)

BackPressed stuff. I'm wondering why you even need the OnBackPressedDispatcher. As you can see, I used it in the earlier examples, basically just for back navigation. However, I then realised I could achieve back navigation via NavOptions. Notice in Graph8Net7 that the code in HandleOnBackPressed is commented out. If you then check Graph8Net7, HandleOnBackPressed is completely removed. This then allows the Predictive Back Gesture to work. Check out both the Readmes for a more detailed explanation.

If you are targeting API 34, are you aware that you can still use Xamarin.Android without the need to move to .Net? You can do that until you target API 35. As you can see, the MS forum is fixated on .NET, so their usual answer to any Android-specific question is you have to migrate to Maui. That really annoys me as it makes it a useless forum and is probably the reason why posts are deleted. Just add  to your manifest. You are good on Google Play until you change to Android 15.

There was another typo in my first comment. Notice in Graph8Net7 that the code in HandleOnBackPressed is commented out. It should read Graph7Net7. For PBG to work on an Android 14 device, you must turn on Predictive Animations in developer options.

You can do that until you target API 35

Yes. See the following: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en. The dates next year won't be exactly the same, depending on when they release 16

@Nathan Sokalski
If you are looking for info on OnBackPressedCallback, you can check out my GitHub. There are two examples: NavigationGraph8Net7 (with it) and NavigationGraph8Net8 (without it). It really depends on what you are trying to do, as it can also create problems; see both readmes. NavigationGraph8Net8 still shows the predictive back when exiting on devices running Android 15 and on 13 and 14 devices with the developer option (Predictive Animations) setting set without any callbacks.
You'd need to describe what you are trying to do for further advice.
I'm not all that sure I want to use it for a normal back swipe between fragments, other than the home fragment (to exit the app). For example, use Android's Settings app, where the predictive back is fully implemented between all screens. I'm not sure I really want those transitions in my app, but I'd be interested in getting user feedback before committing to it or making it an option the user can control if they don't like it.
Google isn't guiding users, either. Even on a Pixel device running Android 15, there are plenty of their apps (even Gmail) that don't use predictive back, even on exit.
https://github.com/gmck

That doesn't seem to answer my question, because I still can't seem to access OnBackPressedCallback. Am I forgetting something? What namespace is OnBackPressedCallback supposed to be? In which of your files do you create your callback? Where do you use it? I feel like my project should have some sort of reference that I am forgetting, but I don't know what that is. I also noticed that even though you have a TargetFramework of net7.0-android, you also have PackageReferences using Xamarin, which is what we are supposed to be moving away from.
